# javascript interface sometimes returns undefined

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

I don't have clear reproduce steps but my javascript function sometimes returns 'undefined' and I can't solve it.

**This is my first javascript call from android, in order to fill some list in html:**

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavascriptInterface(), "android");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {  
                        @Override  
                        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)  
                        {  
                             if(!redirect){
                                  loadingFinished = true;
                               }

                               if(loadingFinished && !redirect){
                                 //HIDE LOADING IT HAS FINISHED
                                   final String paramsurl = "javascript:setProducts(\'" + demoStr + "\', \'" + visitedStr + "\');";

                                    if (webView != null)
                                        webView.loadUrl(paramsurl);
                               } else{
                                  redirect = false; 
                               }


                        }  

                         @Override
                           public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String urlNewString) {
                               if (!loadingFinished) {
                                  redirect = true;
                               }

                               loadingFinished = false;
                               webView.loadUrl(urlNewString);
                               return true;
                           }

                         @Override
                        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                             loadingFinished = false;
                            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                        }


                    });  
                    webView.loadUrl(url);
```

**Later, when the user clicks the send button from android UI I want to receive results from javascript**

```
public void onSave(View v) {
            PIWebView webView = (PIWebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:android.getJsResult(sendFormEvent());");
        }
```

Finally, here is the interface:

```
private class MyJavascriptInterface {

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void getJsResult(String msg) {
            if (msg.equals("undefined")) {
                msg = null;
            }
            mSampleProductJson = msg;

        }
```

Some ideas until now,

- Somehow webview loads second call before first one, but this one
  seems impossible to me because second call is triggered by user click
- JavascriptInterface has confusion with other webview on background?

Comment: This is Java, not JavaScript.

Comment: maybe your JavaScript is just broken? Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: @marcin.kosiba everytime same html,javascript is loaded in webview from device.